# Удаление непечатаемых символов JS RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Всем привет! Столкнулся с интересной задачей: имеется строка, в которой могут содержаться непечатаемые символы(пробел, перевод каретки, табуляция и др.). Необходимо убрать все эти символы, но только с правого и левого краев строки. Если пробелы попадаются в середине строки (между печатаемыми символами), то их нужно оставить. Помогите пожалуйста! Проблема заключается в удалении переноса каретки, с ней я не смог справиться.

Comment: Используйте `mystring.trim()`.

Comment: Так же, если вы поддерживаете старые браузеры, используйте полифил для trim() https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, `.trim()`, но если хочется регекспа, то `new RegExp('(^\\s+|\\s+$)', 'g')` или так `.replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g,"")`

Во-вторых, если пофантазировать и вам нужны чистые абзацы в строке, то это выражение удалит всё что слева и справа в каждом абзаце строки: `.trim().replace(/\s*\n\s*/g,"\n")` - останется только один перенос строки между абзацами.